# Confining a fixed size image inside a div container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` which is relatively positioned inside a wrapper. When the user selects an option an image of predefined size is send to client and is displayed inside this `div`.

But as the `div` is relatively positioned with width and height set in `%`, the image sometimes jumps out of the `div` for low resolution monitors.

How could I Handle this without making any changes in server (changing `img` size)
The size of image is specified in pixels. 
I am using a custom control to create this img which has the limitation like not been able to set width and height in %. I have to specify in pixels.

Comment: Pls post your HTML & CSS code

Comment: Since the image is the fixed size. Keep the width and height fixed for the div. or Keep 'min-width' and 'min-height' for the div

Answer (score 1):

#### You can set image height in % like 90% or 100%.

Comment: NO possible. I am using a devexpress chart control. The control sends a <img> of chart from server  of specified width and height in pixels. I cannot specify in % . Its a limitaion of devexpress chart control

Answer (score 1):

If the image size is 400*400. Keep min-width and min-height of the div as 400 as below.

```
img{
max-width: 400;
max-height: 400;
}
```

Comment: you probably mean max-width ;)

Answer (score 0):

why not setting a max-width in CSS ?

```
div{
 max-width:400px;
 width:50%;
 height:auto;
}

div img{
  max-width:400px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
```

you have both `min-width` and `max-width` to play with :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 img{
      width:100%;
      position:relative;
    }
```